# Filling multiple array's with Standard Input from .txt file

Tags: java, arrays, stdin

I've been struggeling to fill my array's with different types of data from a text file. This text file looks as following:

N String String
double double
double double
etc. N lines of doubles
N String String
  rinse and repeat

So for example:

```
  120 Chicago Illinois  
  34.457832 78.294756  
  34.452948 78.198347
  etc.
```

This is the code I have so far, it's raw, all in the main body. A = 17 and B = 10632. Because there are a total of 10649 lines, of which 17 are an Integer String String line and the rest x and y coordinates

```
//    Read over entire file
    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()){

      String line = StdIn.readLine();
      String[] split = line.split(" ");
//      System.out.print(split.length);
//      if (Character.isDigit(line.charAt(0))){  // Didnt work as to both the integer N and double are a digit 0-9
      if (split.length >= 3){
        for(int i = 0; i < A;i++){
          intArray1[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
          stringArray1[i] = split[1];
          stringArray2[i] = split[2];
        }
      } else{
        for(int i = 0;i < B; i++){
          xcoords[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
          ycoords[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
        }}  
      }
```

The idea was, that if the length of the line created by StdI.readLine and split is 3; it has to be a line in the .txt file starting with an integer N followed by two strings.
  We Should then store those 3 'value's in the 3 arrays of matching types.

Else the length of the line should be 2, containing only 2 double value's and store those respectively.

Comment: So the question is how to test if the first item in `split` is an integer-string?

Comment: I would say you can read it line by line and check for format, or use beanIO as your library to convert it to java objects

Comment: I will give you one example for the simple demo of the first case.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what your arrays and index are for, it will be only saving the latest one unless you have an other index outside and make use of it.

```
//Read over entire file
while (!StdIn.isEmpty()){
    String line = StdIn.readLine();
    String[] split = line.split(" ");
    if (line.contains(".")) {       
        //It is the double double lines
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            intArray1[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
            stringArray1[i] = split[1];
            stringArray2[i] = split[2];
        }
    }else {
        //It is the int String String lines
        for(int i = 0;i < B; i++){
            xcoords[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
            ycoords[i] = Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I will show you my method of doing so:

```
//Create List to store all the useful information
List<IntStringObj> intStrList = new ArrayList<IntStringObj>;
List<DoubleObj> doubleList = new ArrayList<DoubleObj>;

//Read over entire file
while (!StdIn.isEmpty()){
    String line = StdIn.readLine();
    String[] split = line.split(" ");
    if (line.contains(".")) {       
        //It is the double double lines
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            IntStringObj tempIntStrObj = new IntStringObj();
            tempIntStrObj.setInterger(Integer.parseInt(split[0]));
            tempIntStrObj.setStr1(split[1]);
            tempIntStrObj.setStr2(split[2]);
            intStrList.add(tempIntStrObj);
        }
    }else {
        //It is the int String String lines
        for(int i = 0;i < B; i++){
            DoubleObj tmpDoubleObj = new DoubleObj();
            tmpDoubleObj.setDouble1(Double.parseDouble(split[0]));
            tmpDoubleObj.setDouble2(Double.parseDouble(split[1]));
            doubleList.add(tmpDoubleObj);
        }
    }
}

//The classes can be stored outside/inside depends on your usage
class IntStringObj {
    private int interger;
    private String str1;
    private String str2;

    public int getInterger() {
        return interger;
    }

    public void setInterger(int interger) {
        this.interger = interger;
    }

    public String getStr1() {
        return str1;
    }

    public void setStr1(String str1) {
        this.str1 = str1;
    }

    public String getStr2() {
        return str2;
    }

    public void setStr2(String str2) {
        this.str2 = str2;
    }

}

class DoubleObj {
    private double double1;
    private double double2;

    public double getDouble1() {
        return double1;
    }

    public void setDouble1(double double1) {
        this.double1 = double1;
    }

    public double getDouble2() {
        return double2;
    }

    public void setDouble2(double double2) {
        this.double2 = double2;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the database seems pretty consistent you should be able to just hard most of it. I would handle it a bit like this:

```
    List<City> cities =  new ArrayList<>();

    while (!StdIn.isEmpty()){

        String line1 = StdIn.readLine();
        String line2 = StdIn.readLine();
        String line3 = StdIn.readLine();

        String[] arr1 = line1.split(" ");
        String[] arr2 = line1.split(" ");
        String[] arr3 = line1.split(" ");

        int cityNum = arr1[0];
        String cityName = arr1[1] + " " + arr1[2];

        double[] xcoords = new double[2];
        double[] ycoords = new double[2];

        xcoords[0] = Double.parseDouble(arr2[0]);
        xcoords[1] = Double.parseDouble(arr3[0]);

        ycoords[0] = Double.parseDouble(arr2[1]);
        ycoords[1] = Double.parseDouble(arr3[1]);

        City city = new City();
        //build city with info

        cities.add(city);
    }
```

I think doing any sort of test to see what the format is is just extra work for no reason, as long as you are reasonably sure that the format would stay constant.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what the code is doing... the while loop already loops through all the lines so whats the purpose of the for loops? You read a line inside the while loop, then the for loops fill all array elements with copies of the same line. Then you repeat for the next line etc. till you get to the last line and then the arrays are filled with copies of the last line.

1) if you want to maintain the structure, then the [solution of PSo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47192928/5638356) is appropriate except i would put an array of `DoubleObj` as a member of `IntStringObj` class and then only create an `ArrayList` of `IntStringObj` in the main method. Also remove the for loops eg:

```
// Create List to store all the useful information
List<IntStringObj> intStrList = new ArrayList<>();

IntStringObj tempIntStrObj = null;
int index = 0;
// Read over entire file
while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
    String line = StdIn.readLine();
    String[] split = line.split(" ");
    if (!line.contains(".")) {
        tempIntStrObj = new IntStringObj();
        index = 0;
        tempIntStrObj.setInteger(Integer.parseInt(split[0]));
        tempIntStrObj.setStr1(split[1]);
        tempIntStrObj.setStr2(split[2]);
        intStrList.add(tempIntStrObj);
    } else {
        DoubleObj tmpDoubleObj = new DoubleObj();
        tmpDoubleObj.setX(Double.parseDouble(split[0]));
        tmpDoubleObj.setY(Double.parseDouble(split[1]));
        tempIntStrObj.setCoords(index++, tmpDoubleObj);
    }
}
// print to console
/*
for (IntStringObj iso : intStrList) {
    System.out.println(iso.getInteger() + " " + iso.getStr1() + " " + iso.getStr2());
    for (int i = 0; i < iso.getInteger(); i++) {
        System.out.println(iso.getCoords(i).getX() + ", " + iso.getCoords(i).getY());
    }
}
*/

// The classes can be stored outside/inside depends on your usage
class IntStringObj {
    private int integer;
    private String str1;
    private String str2;
    private DoubleObj[] coords;

    public int getInteger() {
        return integer;
    }

    public void setInteger(int integer) {
        this.integer = integer;
        coords = new DoubleObj[integer];
    }

    public String getStr1() {
        return str1;
    }

    public void setStr1(String str1) {
        this.str1 = str1;
    }

    public String getStr2() {
        return str2;
    }

    public void setStr2(String str2) {
        this.str2 = str2;
    }

    public DoubleObj getCoords(int index) {
        return coords[index];
    }

    public void setCoords(int index, DoubleObj coords) {
        this.coords[index] = coords;
    }
}

class DoubleObj {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

2) if you just want a list of coordinates, and a separate list of integers + city / states:

Assuming that N varies for each city / state, you'd be better off using an `ArrayList` which dynamically resizes itself as more space is needed.

```
ArrayList<Double> xcoords = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> ycoords = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> strArray1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> strArray2 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> intArray1 = new ArrayList<>();

// Read over entire file
while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
    String line = StdIn.readLine();
    String[] split = line.split(" ");

    if (split.length >= 3) {
        intArray1.add(Integer.parseInt(split[0]));
        strArray1.add(split[1]);
        strArray2.add(split[2]);
    } else {
        xcoords.add(Double.parseDouble(split[0]));
        ycoords.add(Double.parseDouble(split[1]));
    }
}
// print to console
/*
// print N city state
for (int i = 0; i < intArray1.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(intArray1.get(i) + " " + strArray1.get(i) + " " + strArray2.get(i));
}
// print x, y coords
for (int i = 0; i < xcoords.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(xcoords.get(i) + ", " + ycoords.get(i));
}
*/
```